# How can get and set value of cell contain image?

Tags: vba, excel

My Excel Data:
`Cell1` contain text and image: 
I want get value of `Cell1` set to `Cell2`.
I try :

```
Cell2.Value=Cell1.Value
```

this code only set text, can't get & set image.

How can get and set value of cell contain image?
Thanks all.

Comment: image is not a cell property. When inserted, it is added as a separate object..  please clarify, by image in a cell, are you referring to any formatting applied (icon, bars, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pictures are pasted into a worksheet and then aligned to a cell, not copied into a cell like values

This code copies a picture from A1 to A2:

```
Cells(1, 1).Copy
Cells(2, 1).select
Activesheet.Paste
```

Edit: Here without the `select` statement:

```
Cells(1, 1).Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
```

Edit: As a 1-liner (thank you @Darren)

```
Cells(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1)
```

Comment: You could put the `Destination....` on the same line as the copy:  `Cells(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 1)`

Comment: You could also copy the picture if you know its name:  `Sheet1.Shapes("Picture 1").Copy: Sheet1.Cells(3, 1).PasteSpecial`

Comment: i try this code, but only copy text:  aSheet.Cells(iRow_Src, 5).Copy Destination:=oTargetSheet.Cells(iRow, 5)

Comment: Let's break it down into little steps: try my first 3-line code with an image only, and see if that image gets copied.

Comment: sorry, i copy ok, but size of image very small.

Comment: can i resize image in cell after patse the same original?

Comment: You can assign an object to the copied image and resize it that way. I would suggest to open a new question for this

Comment: Cell1 only has a Image, but after paste to Cell2 has 2 image. Why?